# how to fetch an api and filter names starting with "ka" in node, express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, fetch

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fetch = require('node-fetch');


const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

let users = [];
function getUsers(url) {
    const user = fetch(url)
        .then((res) => {
            res.json().then((res1) => {
                users = res1;
            })
        })
};


const  filterUser = (req,res) => {
    const filteredUser = users.filter(user => user.name.toLowerCase().startsWith('ka'))
    let fresults = res.json(filteredUser)
    return fresults;
}


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(users)
})


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("listening on port 3000");
    getUsers(url)
})
```

fetching an url of users data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users and filter the users starting with username 'Ka' and print the output list

Comment: Hi Rahul and welcome to SO. What's wrong with the code you've presented?

Comment: Really unclear why you have `console.log(filterUser);` and you never call getUsers or filterUser.

Comment: Hi,
I an unable to create a new filtered array , where names start with "ka".
I have declared the  getUsers(url) function inside the app.listen(), and please ingore the console.log(filterUser);, that is just a comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the users and filter them out. You are not calling it in any endpoint

```
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

const getUsers = async (filter) => {
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  const users = await resp.json();
  return filter ? users.filter(filter) : users;
}

const filterUserNameKa = (user) => user.username.toLowerCase().startsWith('ka');


app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const users = await getUsers(filterUserNameKa);
    res.send(users)
})
```